# Custom ArrayAdapter in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I'm trying to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` to use for my `ListFragment`.  Right now nothing is being displayed in the `ListFragment` except for the `TextView` saying what Fragment number it is.  I have put a breakpoint in `getView()` method of my adapter and it is not being called.  I searched for reasons that wouldn't be called and some people seem to think that my ListView is hidden, so I've tried changing the `layout_height` to `wrap_content`, but that didn't work.

Also, I've been following the code from this developer's page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

ListFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment implements FragmentTitle
{
private int mNum = 0;
private String mTitle = "Home";
private ListView mListView;
private MyArrayAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    InfoContainer temp = new InfoContainer("test1", "test2");
    mAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, temp);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
    mListView = (ListView) v1.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return v1;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    Log.i("HomeFragment", "Item clicked: " + id);
}

public CharSequence getTitle() 
{
    return mTitle;
}

}
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InfoContainer>
{
Context mContext;
InfoContainer data;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, InfoContainer temp) 
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    mContext = context;
    this.data = temp;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.id.pager, parent, false);
        holder.v1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);
        holder.v2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listview_data);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    InfoContainer info = data;
    holder.v1.setText(info.name);
    holder.v2.setText(info.text);
    return row;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView v1;
    TextView v2;
}

}
```

fragment_pager_list.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_background"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

I've made custom ArrayAdapters before with no problem, so is there something I'm missing about getting them to work with a ListFragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is that `getCount()` was returning 0 for my ArrayAdapter.  So I just used `mAdapter.add(temp)` and then `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and it worked.  I also had to change the line `row = inflater.inflate(R.id.pager, parent, false);` to `row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);`

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and it was really in getCount(). Its logical because the extended class doesnt use your overloaded items so it doesnt know its size.