# Setting the font ,color for the ArrayAdapter layout

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter

i have a layout like this:

items.xml:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

i am setting this in Array adapter like this:

here array is `String[] array;`

```
adapter.addSection(header, new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.items, array));
```

Now i want to add set color, textsize, custom font progrmatically how to do it?

I know how toset color, textsize  and also custom font but how to get the id of this textview?

Comment: if you want to customize things, why don't you extends that to any other class and write override methods?

Comment: how is that? can you show me any sample code?

Comment: read http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example article.

Comment: `<com.example.MyTextView` instead of `<TextView` in the xml.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 i didnt get you?

Comment: this is how to specify your custom class instead of a standard one in the XML layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want change color, textsize, font of item in listview then you need to implement *ArrayAdapter* methods. Create custom Adapter extends ArrayAdapter and it has **getView** method where you can changed all.

Whenenver ListView shown, ListView ask to give him visible items' view from Adapter and adapter call getView method at this moment you do create item view and return this item view.

Example create use custom adapter ArrayAdapter:

- http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/
- [Am I creating my custom ArrayAdapter correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614934/am-i-creating-my-custom-arrayadapter-correctly)
- [Extending ArrayAdapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379261/extending-arrayadapter-in-android)
- [Custom ArrayAdapter in a ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286287/custom-arrayadapter-in-a-listfragment)

Answer (score 0):

create style in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">

        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

applay it to test view like:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) artical for more detail.

and [You cannot set a view's style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code).

[add custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826701/1168654) here is example of spinner with custom adapter.

Comment: What if i want to add
 custom fonts?

Comment: you can use TypeFace and to give font name, put file in "Assets" directory. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font